# Изменение предложения

Tags: грамматика

Наткнулся на предложение:

*И это случилось со мной, которая видела море.*

Допустимо ли следующая конструкция предложения:

И это случилось со мной, кто видел море.

Кто или которая?
И какое правило здесь?

Спасибо!

Comment: Надо бы с родом определится. Кто же видел море?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"И это случилось со мной, кто видел море." Нужно перестроить предложение. Правило не знаю, но слух режет и понятно, что это не по-русски.

Например так:

И это случилось со мной — с тем, кто видел море.

Первое предложение верно.

Comment: Это само собой ясно. Но вопрос в том, является ли употребление `И это случилось со мной, кто видел море.` допустимым или это грамматическая ошибка? То, что оно плохо звучит, и так понятно.

Answer (score 0):

Оба варианта допустимы.

Чтобы понять разницу, нужно чуть расширить предложения:

`И это случилось со мной, кто видел море.` = `И это случилось со мной - тем, кто видел море.`

`И это случилось со мной, который видел море.` = `И это случилось со мной - таким человеком, который видел море.`

То есть в первом варианте акцент на самом человеке, а во втором - на его качествах.

В русском языке второй вариант звучит лучше, а в английском первый.